# How to configure shared javascript runtime using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, office-js, office-addins, xsd-validation

I am using Visual Studio for creating excel add-in. I also have some server-side code because of which i am using Visual Studio. I wanted to configure shared javascript runtime so that i can open the taskpane using keyboard shortcut.

I see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) but it is using Yeoman generator.
I have seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/keyboard-shortcuts#configure-the-manifest) for how to setup the keyboard shortcuts.

I am getting following errors when adding 'Runtimes' tag under 'Host' tag and 'ExtendedOverrides' tag after 'VersionOverrides' tag respectively.

Error       The element 'Host' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Runtimes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'. List of possible elements expected: 'AllFormFactors, DesktopFormFactor' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.

Error       The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'ExtendedOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'.

Please let me know if there is any example Visual Studio project demonstrating the use of shared javascript runtime.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest schema files that are installed with VS are out of date. You have to manually update them.

1. In Solution Explorer, open the manifest.xml file. The manifest is typically in the first project under your solution.
2. Choose View > Properties Window (F4).
3. In the Properties Window, choose the ellipsis (...) to open the XML Schemas editor. Here you can find the exact folder location of all schema files your project uses.
4. Open the XSD file you want to update in a text editor. The schema name from the validation error will correlate to the XSD file name. For example, open TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0.xsd.
   Locate the updated schema at [[MS-OWEMXML]: Appendix A: Full XML Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/c6a06390-34b8-4b42-82eb-b28be12494a8). For example, TaskPaneAppVersionOverridesV1_0 is at taskpaneappversionoverrides Schema.
   5.Copy the text into your text editor.
5. Save the updated XSD file.
6. Restart Visual Studio to pick up the new XSD file changes.

You can repeat the previous process for any additional schemas that are out-of-date.

Comment: Why don't you consider including XSD file changes in VS updates? Why do we need to do that manually? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: No really good reason. There hasn't been budgeting to maintain VS support for Office Add-ins for a few years. We're hoping that that will change in the next few months.